Snap Steam doesn't detect my second drive
I have a 1tB Hard Disk and i'd like to use it to store games. With the .deb version of steam and with the Flatpack version i can add the Hard Disk and use it but with the Snap version it's not working (when i choose the disk in the settings nothing happens). does anyone came up with a solution to this problem or it's just a Snap issue that can't be fixed?

Is the 1TB disk internal or external (e.g. a USB external disk)?

It's not a snap issue. Confinement and security is a snap feature that many people want. The default setting of that confinement is that snaps can see only your /home directory, and only non-hidden files there. The easy solution is to look up how to bind-mount (not symlink) your HDD into that part of the filesystem. If it's frequently-used storage, it should be in your fstab anyway.

It's an internal 1TB disk. @user535733 Thank you for the explanation. Can i ask you how can i bind-mount my HDD into the part of the filesystem that snap can see?

Please don't put SOLVED in the question title. Click on the Answer Your Own Question button below and write the detailed answer. Then after the mandatory time click on the gray check mark ✔️ next to your answer and turn it green ✅. That marks your answer as answered correctly.

I've solved the problem by writing on terminal sudo snap connect steam:removable-media
